Ubunutu 24 Server LTS install will not boot
I am attempting to install Ubuntu Server onto a Lenovo ThinkStation S30 and after installation off of a Live install DVD, I get the error Reboot and Select Proper Boot device. I have also tried other distros, and I get Error 1962 No operating system found. I suspect it's something related to either the partitions, as Ubuntu 10 does boot, but no later versions do, or something to do with UEFI.

After some reading of another issue and of a previous ask I took down due to it being off-topic as it was related to Ubuntu 10, the problem is that UEFI just doesn't work. So I had to use manual partitioning to remove everything but my main partition and your swap space (which I made 10GB in my install), set my BIOS settings to not use UEFI, and it fully booted.
